# Running shell commands without a shell window

Tags: python, windows, shell, subprocess

With either `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.Popen`, executing a shell command makes a shell window quicky appear and disappear.

How can I run the shell command without the shell window?

Comment: What platform?  (Sounds like Windows.)

Comment: related: [How do I hide the console when I use os.system() or subprocess.call()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7006238/4279)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I imagine your observation is limited to Windows, since that, I believe, is the only platform on which you'll get that "console flash" issue.  If so, then the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen) offer the following semi-helpful paragraph:

> The startupinfo and creationflags, if
>   given, will be passed to the
>   underlying CreateProcess() function.
>   They can specify things such as
>   appearance of the main window and
>   priority for the new process. (Windows
>   only)

Unfortunately the Python online docs do not reproduce the relevant portion of the Windows API docs, so you have to locate those elsewhere, e.g. starting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN which leads you [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863(v=VS.85).aspx) for the `creationflags`, and specifically to

```
CREATE_NO_WINDOW
0x08000000
```

> The process is a console application
>   that is being run without a console
>   window. Therefore, the console handle
>   for the application is not set.

So, adding `creationflags=0x08000000` to your `Popen` call should help (unfortunately I have no Windows-running machine on which to try this out, so you'll have to try it yourself).