# How do I hide the console when I use os.system() or subprocess.call()?

Tags: python, windows, console, subprocess

I wrote some statements like below:

```
os.system(cmd) #do something
subprocess.call('taskkill /F /IM exename.exe')
```

both will pop up a console.

How can I stop it from popping up the console?

Comment: Try using `spawn` family instead.

Comment: related: [Running a process in pythonw with Popen without a console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1813872/4279)

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The process `STARTUPINFO` can hide the console window:

```python
si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
#si.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE # default
subprocess.call('taskkill /F /IM exename.exe', startupinfo=si)
```

Or set the [creation flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags) to disable creating the window:

```
CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000
subprocess.call('taskkill /F /IM exename.exe', creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```

The above is still a console process with valid handles for console I/O (verified by calling `GetFileType` on the handles returned by `GetStdHandle`). It just has no window and doesn't inherit the parent's console, if any.

You can go a step farther by forcing the child to have no console at all:

```
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
subprocess.call('taskkill /F /IM exename.exe', creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS)
```

In this case the child's standard handles (i.e. `GetStdHandle`) are 0, but you can set them to an open disk file or pipe such as `subprocess.DEVNULL` (3.3) or `subprocess.PIPE`.

Comment: `creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW` does no seem to be very portable

Comment: @Cyan, in what sense is `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` not portable? This is a Windows question, and these flags should be supported in all versions of Windows NT, from 3.1 to Windows 10.

Comment: Python 3.7 now has [subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)

Comment: @Harmon758, I'm aware. The priority-class creation flags were being added, and I suggested that we may as well add some of the others, including the console flags `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` and `DETACHED_PROCESS` and two others that are unrelated to the console -- `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` and `CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE`.

Comment: @eryksun My apologies, I didn't mean to imply that you weren't already aware of its existence. I didn't see it mentioned here yet, so I wanted to provide the information to anyone who came across this issue, since this answer has high visibility for it.

Comment: @Harmon758, it's going to be a while before code can rely on them, since scripts may have to support  3.5, 3.6, and even 2.7. But I wanted to at least get them in the docs for visibility.

Comment: Thank you @ErykSun but no single one of them worked for me,I tried them 1by1. I use anaconda to run R from Python. but the window always opens

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti, I don't use either Anaconda or R, so I can only suggest that you try to systematically identify the problem. Factor out Anaconda and your current Python environment by installing and using the regular [Python 3.7 distribution](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-374) with default settings and no third-party packages. For 64-bit Windows, I recommend the "x86-64 executable" installer. In your test script, check `sys.executable` to ensure that you're running the new Python installation and not your old Anaconda installation.

Comment: @ErykSun Thank you very much dear Eryk. well one point is that I have written many other codes using this idle, and I am afraid if I do only this part in 3.7 it might create difficulties for me. since I will need to gather all of the codes under one thkinter or executable file, will this solution help me ?

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti, it's not the final solution. It's the first step in the systematic narrowing down of what's causing the child R process to allocate a console. We begin by simplifying the Python side of things as much as possible. If the problem persists, it's likely in the R child process, perhaps due to command-line arguments or environment variables that make it allocate a console.

Answer (score 31):

Add the `shell=True` argument to the subprocess calls.

```
subprocess.call('taskkill /F /IM exename.exe', shell=True)
```

Or, if you don't need to wait for it, use `subprocess.Popen` rather than `subprocess.call`.

```
subprocess.Popen('taskkill /F /IM exename.exe', shell=True)
```

Comment: Sure, the startupinfo technique works, but this one's shorter (but put a comment in to indicate why you're using `shell=True` otherwise it probably wouldn't be as obvious).

Comment: Hmm, for some reason my executable not running when using `shell=True`. But it run just fine when using startupinfo.

Comment: @arifwn: post a new question, please.

Comment: +1 for brevity. This way has subprocess [configure `STARTUPINFO` for you](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Lib/subprocess.py#l918). Note that running via `cmd /c` should only be used with trusted commands. In this case it's OK.

Comment: Not a good solution. shell=True does more than you want, and opens up security problems if the user can manipulate the input.

Comment: Don't we want shell=False? Aren't we hiding the console window?

Comment: @BuvinJ: look at the code to see what it does. You’re misunderstanding the purpose of `shell` (look at the docs too). This answer is basically taking a side-effect of `shell=True` and using it.

Comment: Ok.  Well, I first tried opening notepad in Windows with os.system.  That displayed a console window. I tried subprocess.call per your post and it did not open that extra window.  I set shell=False though.  It worked for my purpose, and the official docs say not to use shell=True if you don't have to. (See jmnben's comment)

Comment: @BuvinJ: notepad doesn’t open a console under any circumstances. It doesn’t use the console subsystem. We’re talking about processes that *do* use the console subsystem, and stopping them from showing a console window.

Comment: I see.  Sorry about that.  I was looking to prevent the command prompt window from popping up when I ran a simple exe.  This fixed that as well!

Comment: Just FYI, this solution might make the child not see that its input has closed if the parent Python program closes the input pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:
`subprocess.call('powershell.exe taskkill /F /IM exename.exe', shell=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a wrapper that checks for Windows OS since `subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW` throws an error on non Windows OS. The window opening is only an issue on Windows OS.

```py
def subprocess_run(command, **kwargs):
    if (os.name == 'nt'):
        kwargs.setdefault('creationflags', subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
    return subprocess.run(command, **kwargs)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#windows-constants

Answer (score -2):

Try `subprocess.Popen(["function","option1","option2"],shell=False)`.

Comment: sorry, the stuff I want to invoke cannot be run by subprocess.Popen, coz exception raised "invalid win32 app". But os.system can run it without any warning.

Comment: Er, that's not a problem with subprocess; I can run it on Windows 7, natively (Python 2.7.2) as well as under Cygwin (Python 2.6.5), with no warnings.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the console still pops up. Also the `shell` argument defaults to `False`. Explicitly passing it should not make a difference.

Answer (score -4):

Try to change the extension from .py to .pyw

Its basically just a Python User Interface file. So it opens up a new Window without the command line. chech this link (filext.com/file-extension/PYW)

Comment: Hi, please provide some additional narrative to explain how this answers the question. Thanks.

Comment: Its basically just a Python User Interface file. So it opens up a new Window without the command line. chech this link (https://filext.com/file-extension/PYW)

Comment: Please edit the actual answer to include this useful information, thank you.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question, which is about using a subprocess() call within an already-running Python app (whether that runs in a console window or not).