# Python kill a process without a shell

Tags: python, python-2.7, process, subprocess, kill

I am making a program to do a bit of process management for me on windows 10.

In order to kill unneeded processes I am using the following command:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("taskkill /F /im "+unwantedProcess, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Where unwanted process is the full name of a process I want to kill. I have also tried using:

```
os.system("taskkill /F /im "+unwantedProcess)
```

Now this works fine when it is interpreted or compiled using pyinstaller. The problem comes when I use the

```
--noconsole
```

command in pyinstaller. It works in all other instances except when there in no console (since I do not want a console opened in the background). Any idea how to fix this?

Edit: After editing the code I inserted a very basic error catch statement as follows:

```
try:
    subprocess.Popen("taskkill /F /im skype.exe", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
except Exception as e:
    f = open("error.txt", "w")
    f.write(str(e))
    f.close()
```

Using skype as an example process to kill. It still killed it successfully when the program was interpreted or compiled with a console. However, when it was compiled using the

```
--noconsole
```

command once again I got this output in my error file:

```
[Error 6] The handle is invalid
```

Skype was definitely open when I ran this program

Comment: Did you try with the full path of taskkill? Did you try to catch exceptions?

Comment: Made an edit with the error catching results in the question

Comment: Check out this document [https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-subprocess](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-subprocess)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are calling python with the `--no-console` option makes your process not suitable for console I/O (i.e. what you need to call `taskkill`).

If you really want to hide the console and still have a valid process handle, there are different ways to do it.  Look at the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7006238/4515566)