# Equivalent of os.system without a console window?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.4, windows-console

I have a line that I can use it with `os.system` like;

```
os.system("ffmpeg -i file.smh -acodec libmp3lame file.mp3")
```

Where `ffmpeg` is an exe file. But It creates a console window on the screen. Normally I hide the console window by the following:

```
import win32console,win32gui

win = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(win,1)
```

I tried this but it didn't work. `os.system` still shows me the console window. So I have two options:

- I need a way to hide the console window if I use `os.system`.
- Or I need a `subprocess` equivalent of `os.system`.

I tried to use `subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg.exe -i file.smh -acodec libmp3lame file.mp3"])`, but it can't find ffmpeg.exe.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg.exe -i file.smh -acodec libmp3lame file.mp3"])`

should be:

```
subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg.exe", "-i", "file.smh", "-acodec", "libmp3lame file.mp3"])
```

The way you hade it, your OS will look for an executable named `ffmpeg.exe -i ...` rather than an executable named `ffmpeg` with `-i`, `file.smh`, ... as arguments

If splitting the arguments is problematic for some reason, you can use `shlex.split` to correctly split the arguments for you (It'll handle splitting quoted arguments correctly).

Comment: Solved, thanks for the answer.

Comment: This doesn't prevent creating a console window if ffmpeg.exe is a console application. I list several ways to hide the console in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7006424/205580).

Comment: @eryksun You know what is funny? I actually used a way from your answer before you commented :).