# OS.SYSTEM Hide pop up cmd

Tags: windows, python-3.x

If I run Hello.pyw

```
import os
os.system('start hello.exe')
```

I get a very popup cmd.
How do I run this script without cmd popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lose `start` from your command.

According to [*start* MSDN page or `start /?`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx):

> Starts a **separate** window to run a specified program or command.

```
os.system('hello.exe')
```

Or if instead of *hello.exe* you need to run a bat/cmd file, use `cmd /c` (`cmd /?` for full *cmd* options):

```
os.system('cmd /c "hello.bat"')
```

Comment: There's no point in using `cmd /c` with `os.system`. That runs `cmd.exe /c cmd /c "hello.bat"`. Also, both of the commands in this answer still create a temporary console window when run from pythonw.exe (i.e. a .pyw script). `os.system` uses the cmd shell, which is a console program, so Windows automatically creates a console. Using `start` actually creates two console windows if the target (e.g. hello.exe) is also a console program. Instead, use subprocess to hide the console or prevent it from being created, as I [show here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7006424/205580).