# how to run tesseract without the prompt popping up?

Tags: python, cmd, tesseract

when i run tesseract a prompt pops up, and sometimes that gets over what i need tesseract to read.

`result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(img), config="-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ-_+*/!@#$%^&() -psm 4 -oem 1")`

is there a way to hide the prompt?

i have the same problem as this guy `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782124/how-can-i-hide-the-console-window-when-i-run-tesseract-with-pytesser`
no reply in that question.

Comment: Look at the first comment of question you related to, it solved issue stated in that question: "You're currently working in IDLE, in which case I don't think it really matters if a console window pops up. If you're planning to develop a GUI app with this library, then you'll need to modify the subprocess.Popen call in pytesser.py to hide the console. I'd first try the CREATE_NO_WINDOW process creation flag"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide the console window when I run tesseract with pytesseract with CREATE\_NO\_WINDOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732328/how-to-hide-the-console-window-when-i-run-tesseract-with-pytesseract-with-create)