# Wait for process to open in python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-runtime, runtime

I'm trying make python program which waits to process to open and then it does few things, 
in my case those "few things" will be in function named action(). 
I'm a little complicated with this, here's what I did until now. 
I've found that function which checks if process is running from the tasklist.exe

```
def isWindowsProcessRunning( exeName ) :            
    import subprocess    
    process = subprocess.Popen( 
        'tasklist.exe /FO CSV /FI "IMAGENAME eq %s"' % exeName,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True )
    out, err = process.communicate()    
    try : return out.split("\n")[1].startswith('"%s"' % exeName)
    except : return False
```

And I thought to use that in that way:

```
if( isWindowsPrecessRunning("chrome.exe") == False ):
    print "Waiting for chrome to open.."
    while( True ):
        if( isWindowsPrecessRunning("chrome.exe") == True ):
            action()
else:
    print "Chrome must be closed when the program starts, please close chrome, and re-open the program"
```

The problem is that the program was built with "tkinter" for windows, 
and while I turn it on once, and chrome isn't running - the program gets into endless loop. 
That endless loop, prevent the user of the program to do anything, because it opens a clear cmd, and closes it, opens it, closes it and so over- the user can't even close it. 
Does anyone have an idea about how to do it? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Because of the statement `while( True ):` the program will indeed be in an endless loop. So you need to decide what should happen in the case where the exeName program isn't running.

Comment: Note that an `if` statement already evaluates the boolean value and parentheses are neither required nor desired for control statements. Also, unless you need to comply with a project or organization coding standard, it's recommended to follow PEP 8 style. So it's idiomatic in Python to write `if not is_windows_process_running("chrome.exe")` instead of `if( isWindowsProcessRunning("chrome.exe") == False )`.

Comment: For the problem, I recommend using the [wmi module](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html#monitoring) with the [`Win32_Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372) class. The tutorial shows an example that allows efficiently waiting for a process to start instead of polling. Creating a list of all "chrome.exe" processes is equally simple: `[p for p in c.Win32_Process() if p.Name == 'chrome.exe']`. If the list is empty, then wait for a chrome.exe process to start.

Comment: Regarding the running of background console processes (e.g. tasklist.exe) from a GUI program, use either `creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS` or `creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW`, as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7006424/205580).