# Automatically restarting Python Script on Exception

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a really complicated Python script going on, sometimes it just gets an error, and the only way to debug this, is restarting it, because everything else would make no sense and the error would come back in no time (I already tried a lot of things, so please dont concentrate on that)

I want a .bat script (im on Windows unfortunately) that restarts my python script, whenever it ends.
Another python script is also fine.

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: just create bat file add set env=python.exe
start python script.py

Comment: But that only starts the python file, it doesnt restart it, when it crashs?

Comment: tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq python.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "python.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Program is running

Comment: Can you please write that into a gist or ghostbin?

Comment: Take a look at forever (https://github.com/foreverjs/forever).

Comment: @jarmod Isnt Foreverjs for js files?

Comment: You can use forever to run scripts continuously (whether it is written in node.js or not).

Comment: Foreverjs doesnt work for me

Answer (score 1):

```
set env=python.exe  
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq python.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "python.exe">NUL if "%ERRORLEVEL%"!="0(
   start python script.py
)
```

Other way from python to execute python

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

def processExists(processname):
    tlcall = 'TASKLIST', '/FI', 'imagename eq %s' % processname
    # shell=True hides the shell window, stdout to PIPE enables
    # communicate() to get the tasklist command result
    tlproc = subprocess.Popen(tlcall, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # trimming it to the actual lines with information
    tlout = tlproc.communicate()[0].strip().split('\r\n')
    # if TASKLIST returns single line without processname: it's not running
    if len(tlout) > 1 and processname in tlout[-1]:
        print('process "%s" is running!' % processname)
        return True
    else:
        print(tlout[0])
        print('process "%s" is NOT running!' % processname)
        return False



if not processExists('python.exe')
   call(["python", "your_file.py"])
```

Comment: ? This still isnt clear code, also it doesnt execute my python file, where do I have to put the folder in where the .py is in?

Comment: add python to your environment variable .. set env = "To your path python.exe"

Comment: Sorry I  have no clue of batch

Comment: set env="C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32 python.exe"
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq python.exe" 2>NUL
find /I /N "python.exe">NUL if "%ERRORLEVEL%"!="0( start python sh2bot.py )

Comment: right click ..create new file as text add your commands and save it as .bat

Comment: Lets say I want to execute the script named sh2bot.py in the folder C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32 what should I put into the bat

Comment: Just add the path start python C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\sh2bot.py

Comment: Like this? The bat executes and closes immediately after

Comment: nvm got it running i think

Comment: yes you can either open cmd and paste those commands ..if you want to see execution

Comment: Go widnows start -> cmd ->right click start as administartor->paste your commands

Comment: For the python script: Where do I specify the path?And I get a lot of compile errors, so whats the script for starting sh2bot at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\

Comment: In general, using `shell=True` isn't a good way to hide the console window if a console application such as tasklist.exe creates a new console. It's fine here, but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7006424/205580) for alternatives. That said, simply searching for a "python.exe" process is a bad idea. In general, there could be multiple instances of python.exe running across multiple Windows sessions. Instead, the script can be modified to respawn itself and wait on the child as a watchdog process, preferably using a Job object that kills the child if the parent is killed.