# How to Run Executable in Python Without Pop Up Console of The Executable?

Tags: python, windows, console

So, I have a python script that run a Tkinter GUI which have a button widget that call executable that is written in C. But, everytime I click that button, a console that running that C executable pop up and then close after it's done running. I call the executable using

```
import subprocess    
subprocess.call[args]
```

How to hide that pop up? Because I'm using GUI and it's kinda not nice if console pop up nowhere.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "C executable". If you mean an executable originally written in C and now compiled, the fact it was written in C is rather irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: I guess this is on windows? Then it's a limitation of win32 ... applications are either marked `gui` or `console` and for the latter, a new console is attached by default if there isn't already one. You could call [`CreateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) yourself, passing a `DETACHED_PROCESS` creation flag to avoid it.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Oh, I don't know the name for that *.exe file. So, I named it C executable. But yes, that's what I mean, executable that written in C which is compiled.

Comment: @fahadh4ilyas If my assumption is correct -- add a windows or winapi tag.  I don't know how to call `CreateProcess()` from python, but someone else might know. And btw, it indeed doesn't matter which language was used to compile a "native" executable.

Comment: Related if not a duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7006238/694576

Comment: @alk looks like an exact duplicate to me and has a good answer...

Comment: @alk at least if OP *indeed* talks about windows ... no clarification so far

Comment: @FelixPalmen in a comment OP says they're trying to start a "*.exe file", so I guess yes, it's about Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `startupinfo` parameter of `subprocess.Popen()` [class](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

```
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
subprocess.Popen(command, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

If you wish to pass arguments to the process you should pass it as an array to `popen`:

```
subprocess.Popen(['program.exe','arg1','arg2'], startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

**Edit:**
As Felix pointed out in the comments, in case that you want the child to don't have console at all you should use the `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag and `subprocess.call`.

As described in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx) MSDN page:

> **DETACHED_PROCESS** *0x00000008* - For console processes, the new process does not inherit its parent's
>   console (the default). The new process can call the AllocConsole
>   function at a later time to create a console. For more information,
>   see Creation of a Console. This value cannot be used with
>   CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE.

```
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
subprocess.call('program.exe', creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS)
```

Comment: Ok, this will **hide** the console window. Chances are the called program doesn't even **need** a console, in that case, using the `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag would be better.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I use same variable for showing pop up that's why it's not working. But, now it's working perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Comment: When creating a detached process, generally it's most reliable to set a standard handle to `NUL` (i.e. `subprocess.DEVNULL`) if it isn't set to a pipe. If you leave the standard handle unset, some programs may crash because they assume it's always defined for a console application.