# Do not show console with .exe created by Pyinstaller

Tags: python, cmd, console, pyinstaller

I want to create a very simple .exe which runs another .exe that exist on a shared server. The reason for this is so I can update the .exe on the server without having the users having to update their app. I hope that makes sense..

Anyway, I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of the console that pops up.
The script that calls the program on the server is just:

```
import os
os.system('U:/.../Program.exe')
```

And I create both .exe by running:

```
pyinstaller -w -F -i image.ico name.py
```

(-w should remove console)

I've also tried:

```
pyinstaller -w -F -i image.ico --noconsole name.py
```

without success.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried placing the `--noconsole` argument to the right of the target?

So it'd read `pyinstaller -w -F -i image.ico name.py --noconsole`?

Comment: After some reading, it looks like the output is being generated by the process you're starting using your python script, the `program.exe` in your example, rather than the initial script. --noconsole only hides the console for the frozen script, not for all processes stemming from it. See this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006238/how-do-i-hide-the-console-when-i-use-os-system-or-subprocess-call

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you so much Collin for taking the time and finding that thread! It worked! I'm very grateful