# How can i remove the blinking of the command window while running a gekko MPC code in offline mode?

Tags: python, gekko

I have built several successful codes for MPC using Gekko python in offline mode. However, i still want to remove the blinking of the command window while running the program. Any suggestions ? Thank you.

Comment: I'll take a look at some of these suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006238/how-do-i-hide-the-console-when-i-use-os-system-or-subprocess-call

Comment: I was going to ask this question too. The flashing screen doesn't happen when in an IPython notebook with local solve. The new version of gekko resolves the problem.

Comment: Exactly, updating gekko solves the problem as explained by Professor John.

Answer (score 0):

**New Version Edit**

The [latest version of Python Gekko](https://pypi.org/project/gekko/) (v0.2.4) removes the command window pop-up when solving locally on Windows. To upgrade gekko to the latest version use:

`pip install gekko --upgrade`

or if using an IPython notebook run the cell:

`!pip install gekko --upgrade`

The additional argument `--user` may be required if the Python install requires administrative privilege.

**Original Response**

When using `remote=False`, the new command window is removed with the addition of `shell=True` to the subprocess call.

```py
app = subprocess.Popen([apm_exe, self._model_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, \
       stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd = self._path, bufsize=4096, \
       env = {"PATH" : self._path }, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
```

I'll implement this in the next Gekko release or you can modify your `gekko.py` file in `Python\Lib\site-packages\gekko` around line 1880.

Comment: Dear Professor, thank you for your comments. I added what you recommended after m = GEKKO(remote=False) and I imported subprocess. However, once I ran the code, an error saying " apm_exe is not defined" has appeared.

Comment: You can't add it to your script. You need to modify it in gekko.py in your Python installation folder `Lib\site-packages\gekko` or just wait for the next version of Gekko to be released and upgrade with `pip install gekko --upgrade` at a command terminal.

Comment: The new version of Gekko is now available. You can upgrade with `pip install gekko --upgrade` or `pip install gekko --user --upgrade` (if you don't have admin privilege).